# How to pass a reference array into a setter?

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method called setTo5 which is passed a reference to an array of ints and sets the contents of that array to all 5s. This is what I have so far, and it's giving me an error on the second line after public static void main(...);. How to make a better setter?

```
public class Set5 {
    private static int n = 8;
    static int[] boop = new int[n];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] roop = new int[n];
        roop.setTo5(5);

    }

    public void setTo5(int poop){
        for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
        poop = boop[i];

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any proper setter method in your code.

Comment: would I have to, write this.n = poop? I am not very versed in setters at the moment.

Comment: Arrays in Java do not implement a `setTo5()` method.  You need to call methods on the types on which they are implemented.

Comment: How to make a better setter? this sentence is very confusing, In java when we mean setter and getter, its completely taken in a very different perspective. By setter we mean setting a value to a variable and by getter we mean extracting a value from a variable and we even follow certain naming conventions too for setter and getter methods. Can you be more clear on  your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class Set5 {
    private static int n = 8;
    static int[] boop = new int[n];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] roop = new int[n];  

        //Create instance of Set5 class  to call setter
        Set5 set5reference = new Set5(); 

        set5reference.setTo5(roop);

        //All the values in roop will now be 5 as set by setter.

    }

    //change this method to accept array reference like this
    public void setTo5(int[] poop){
        for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++){
            poop[i] = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing the OP's homework for them is not particularly productive.  It's better to give them pseudo-code and/or hints. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I understand. But OP tried to workout something. It did not work. I tried to explain what and how that will work. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect about helping with specific problems.

Comment: Thanks, but when I print it out, I get some kind of address code. What went wrong?

Comment: You will again have to add a for-loop to iterate over `roop` variable and prints values like `roop[i]` inside loop.

Answer (score 1):

To fill an array entirely with some value use:

```
java.util.Arrays.fill(poop, 5)
```

In your case:

```
public class Set5 {
    private static int n = 8;
    //static int[] boop = new int[n]; // unused variable

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] roop = new int[n];
        setTo5(roop);
        print(roop);
    }

    public static void setTo5(int[] poop){
        java.util.Arrays.fill(poop, 5)
       // for(int i = 0; i<poop.length ; i++){
       //    poop[i]=5;

        //}
    }

    public static void print(int[] poop){
         for(int i = 0; i<poop.length ; i++){
           System.out.println("array["+i+"] = "+poop[i]);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @dognose there's a local variable called `roop`. The code compiles and works, but it can be improved (a lot)

Comment: @dognose, you make three comments and vote down while i was editing this post. Because I was focused to help, and I try to give the answar ASAP. Please rethink your behavior. It is easy to vote down, it is harder to give at least some answer.

Comment: Even when I use this method, I get this: [I@659e0bfd     Why is that?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I downvoted because your first Answer was nothing but the code pasted again, containing 2 errors that would not compile. Think about your answer before posting it. There is no need to *be the first*, quality matters. Please rethink your behavior.

Comment: Surely, there is a need to be the first if you wish to get reputation points. My code would not compile at the first time, because it was pseudo-code which i have right to post in this case, it was good enough to show the idea and language tools, it was not copy-pasted, it has the change that should be used for solvng the problem.

Comment: @userb you should print array in a for statement, not by .toString();